# A true Electronic Distributor

Tags: toyota, camry, distributor

Is the distributor in a 1993 Camry considered (electronic) ignition system?  I've noticed that it has points & a condenser that can be replaced inside of it

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! [Looking at the one](https://www.rockauto.com/info/106/D9077_3-4Top_1818865__ra_p.jpg), it looks electronic to me. Has all the guts of an electronic one... there's a Hall effect sensor right underneath the rotor ... I'm not seeing a condenser or points in it, so don't really know what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely Electronic, here is the diagram for the 4 cylinder, v6 is similar.

Points started phasing out in the mid 1970's.

[image]